# Register for SMS Notification

Tags: ios, iphone, ios6

Can I register for SMS Notification through my application? All I want is to increase counter in my application when user is doing any SMS out of my application.

Comment: No possible without private API/jailbreak

Comment: Read somewhere that iMessage broadcasting notification? But couldn't find proper way to do that. Do you have any idea about that?

Answer (score 0):

The sandbox nature of apps on the iOS platform prevents you from seeing what the other apps are doing.  You will need to track what you are setting up with your `MFMessageComposeViewController` as you are helping them prepare to send an SMS message.  But you can't tell if they added other recipients or deleted the ones you set up originally.

You can use the delegate to find out if the message was successfully sent, cancelled, or failed.

You get the result in `messageComposeViewController:didFinishWithResult:`

Comment: I want to know, if user is doing SMS using iMessage then can my application receive any notification for that?

Comment: Definitely not.  Not unless you jailbreak your phone.

Answer (score 0):

Nice try NSA!

Seriously though, SMS (text messaging), phone calls and e-mails are all "walled gardens" on the iPhone. This functionality belongs to the OS only, and there is little to no chance that Apple will ever open it up to developers. The other term thrown around is "sandbox" and these system level apps are in it.

Think about the potential consequences if every app could access your text's, e-mails and phone calls (even if it was just the meta-data). What kind of a world would it be when Candy Crush launched an alert the next time you played that said "We noticed you've been getting a lot of messages from Jennifer recently, would you like to invite her to play candy crush too?"

Comment: I do not want the content of SMS, or from whom the SMS has received. All I want is number of SMS user did for the day. Android has feature, to register for SMS Broadcasting. So is there any way to register for such type of notification in my application?

Comment: You can compose a message and hand it off, then you can listen for if it succeeded in sending or not. That's it! Everything else is un-available to you, including how many text messages they've sent or received.