# How to get notified when new SMS is received in iOS

Tags: ios, notifications, message, private

Is there any way to get notified when new message is received in iOS using public or private frameworks.

Comment: refer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14494849/sms-notifications-in-ios6

Answer (score 1):

Apple doesn't allow to do this. If this app is not to release in Appstore, you may find some private frameworks. I think jailbrocken devices can do that. But I don't recommend to jailbreak your device. Understand that these restrictions are for the safety of the user and try to work within these limitations.

Comment: I don't have to publish the app on App Store that is why I mentioned use of Private Frameworks. But it should work in non jailbroken devices.

Comment: There's a similar question in this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19650136/register-for-sms-notification